# Integral and recurrence relation

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-kx}dx$$

So i will summarize here. I want to find the general value of this integral for any integers values of n.

$$\phi_{n} = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-kx} dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} \frac{e^{-kx}}{-k}dx = \frac{n}{k}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n-1} e^{-kx} = \frac{n \phi_{n-1}}{k}$$

So, we want the answer to $$\phi_{n} = \frac{n \times  \phi_{n-1}}{k}$$

I have noticed that the answer of this relation is $$\phi_n = \frac{n!}{k^{n}}$$

Obviously wrong, for $n=0$. Ok, i can understand that. But at least for $n \neq 0$ i would expect it right. But it is not.

Comment: $\phi_0=\frac1k$. Correcting this would yield the desired result

Comment: @DatBoi I know. I want to know where have i made a mistake

Comment: Note
$$\phi_{n} = \frac{n}{k}\phi_{n-1}
= \frac{n(n-1)}{k^2}\phi_{n-2} =\cdots =\frac{n!}{k^n}\phi_{0} = \frac{n!}{k^{n+1}} $$

Comment: @Quanto Exactly! Did you get this now, OP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the Laplace transform of $t^n$ which is given by the

formula $n!/k^{n+1}$, provided of course that $k>0$!! You just missed a

+1 in the exponent in the denominator!

Comment: It is very annoying to give a correct answer ang get a downvote! I think some people may need some medical care or help from a psychologist! This is a very well known formula! It can be found in any table of Laplace transforms and it is easy to prove!

Answer (score 1):

As @Quanto said, $\phi_{0}$ was mistaken as $1$ instead of $\frac{1}{k}$,  $$ 
\begin{aligned}
\phi_{n} &=\frac{n}{k} \phi_{n-1} \\
&=\frac{n}{k} \cdot \frac{n-1}{k} \cdots \frac{1}{k}\phi_{0} \\
&=\frac{n !}{k^{n}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-k x} d x \\
&=\frac{n !}{k^{n+1}}
\end{aligned}
$$
On the other hand, it can be evaluated using Gamma Function as below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n} e^{-k x} d x &\stackrel{kx\mapsto x}{=}   \frac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{k^{n}} e^{-x} d x \\
&= \frac{1}{k^{n+1}}\Gamma(n+1)\\
&= \frac{n !}{k^{n+1}}
\end{aligned}
$$